# Is possible search an element array from input?

Tags: javascript, arrays, if-statement

I'm creating a little script to try and search for an element in the array based on input.

```css
var modulo = document.getElementById("modulo").value;
var link = [
  "http://www.forumfree.it/",
  "http://www.forumcommunity.net/",
  "http://www.blogfree.net/",
];
if(modulo.indexOf(link) > -1) {
  alert("Your site is:" + modulo);
} 

else {
  alert("Sorry, I don't found:" + modulo)
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>Search element in array</title>
</head>
<body>
<input type="text" id="modulo" class="form">
</body>
</html>
```

Anyone can explain to me how to do that (if there's another way to do it better, inform me), and why my code doesn't run? Thanks!

**Code explanation:** I've used `var modulo` to contain the value of the `input`. Then I've created a variable to contain the link. Then `if-else statement` and `indexOf` to search and find it.

## Thanks, the code solution is: https://plnkr.co/edit/bDt4n34KBFAvZrSWmb4a?p=preview

Comment: What type of input would go into `modulo` though?

Comment: `type="text"`, I'ts a text input

Comment: Where are you putting the script? I don't see any reference to a submit input or anything like a button

Comment: Let me clarify. What would you expect the user to type in? Are you expecting something like `forum`?

Comment: You might wanna look into an event to trigger your code doing that, as well as doing what @SulZ suggested in his answer.

Comment: I've tried this but again not works: https://jsfiddle.net/3a3x8ozd/2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try with this plunker https://plnkr.co/edit/bDt4n34KBFAvZrSWmb4a?p=preview it used event trigger to have a button to search website :

```
<button onclick="myFunction()">Search</button>
```

and I wrote your code into a function.

I hope this will help you

The final state :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <input type="text" id="modulo" class="form">
  <button onclick="myFunction()">Search</button>
</body>
```

```
var link = [
  "http://www.forumfree.it/",
  "http://www.forumcommunity.net/",
  "http://www.blogfree.net/",
];

function myFunction() {
  var input = document.getElementById("modulo");
  var results = [];
  for(var i = 0; i < link.length; i++) {
    if(link[i].indexOf(input.value) > -1) {
    results.push(link[i]);
  }
}
if(results.length == 1) {
  alert("Your site is:" + results[0]);
} 
else if (results.length > 1){
  alert("Sorry, your search return more than one result:" + results)
}
else {
  alert("Sorry, I don't found:" + input.value)
}
```

}

Comment: Thanks, this works very good! But I would that If I search: forumfree.i (for examples) the alert return me: Your site is: http://forumfree.it, is it possible?

Comment: without the http ? or you want the complete result value ?

Comment: I edited the plunker to show the result instead of the input value.

Comment: the complete result value

Comment: Put a copy of the final code in your answer to help others instead of external link in comments

Answer (score 1):

You have

```
if(modulo.indexOf(link) > -1)
```

but I think that it should be

```
if(link.indexOf(modulo) > -1)
```

Assuming that modulo is a single string element, this will search the link array for that element and return the index of that element.

Comment: The user has to be very exact though, a missing end slash could make it not found

Comment: Very true, this is definitely not the best practice for whatever they are trying to do. But this is the most obvious error in the logic, from my perspective.

Comment: I don't think that is this, I would that searching also only forumfree.i (for examples) return me alert in if. See my fiddle and try to put in input forumfree.it and don't runs https://jsfiddle.net/3a3x8ozd/1/

Comment: Have you other idea for create my script?

Comment: It's a combination of a JavaScript event trigger,  indexof per string

Answer (score 0):

I think you were on the right track. You just need a few things:

- a button to initiate the search
- put your code in a function so you can call it
- you want to search the array `link` for the value of the input `modulo`

```js
function findIt() {
  var modulo = document.getElementById("modulo").value;
  var link = [
    "http://www.forumfree.it/",
    "http://www.forumcommunity.net/",
    "http://www.blogfree.net/",
  ];
  if (link.indexOf(modulo) > -1) {
    alert("Your site is:" + modulo);
  } else {
    alert("Sorry, I don't found:" + modulo)
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>Search element in array</title>
</head>

<body>
  <input type="text" id="modulo" class="form">
  <input type="button" onclick="findIt()" value="find it">
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function runscript() {
  var modulo = document.getElementById("modulo").value;
  var link = [
    "http://www.forumfree.it/",
    "http://www.forumcommunity.net/",
    "http://www.blogfree.net/",
  ];
  var found = false;
  for(var i = 0; i < link.length; i++) {
    if (link[i].indexOf(modulo) > -1) {
      alert("Your site is:" + link[i]);
      found = true;
    } 
  }

  if (!found) {
    alert("Sorry, I don't found:" + modulo)
  }
}
```

And the HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>Search element in array</title>
</head>
<body>
<input type="text" id="modulo" class="form">
<input type="button" onclick="runscript()" value="search" />
</body>
</html>
```

You will need to press button for search